# While Writing Error Log Text in log File Text Formatting Change in Hosting Environment

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Localhost created FIle like this : - Template ID          | Node Tree                                                                                            | Row Number           | Column Name                                        | Error Type           | Error Description

[image: Localhost Downloaded File Look like This]

Hosted Environment created FIle like this :

Template ID | Node Tree | Row Number | Column Name | Error Type | Error 
Description.

[image: in Hosted Environment Downloaded File Look like This]

if (File.Exists(filename))
            {

```
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filename))
                {

                    int nlength = -80;
                     string format = "{0,-20} | {1,"+nlength+"} | {2,-20} | {3,-50} | {4,-20} | {5,-20}";
                    if (new FileInfo(filename).Length == 0)
                    {
                        string Header = string.Empty;

                        Header = string.Format(format, "Column 1", ""Column 2", ""Column 3", "Column Name 4", ""Column 5", "Error Description" + line);


                    }

                    error = string.Format(format, TempteID, NodTree, Rober, ColName, prmType, prmMessage + line);


                    sw.WriteLine(error);
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                }
```

I am using Stream Writer in C#. that is Write SOme Error Lines in the Text FIle in AppData Folder.

While i am Running this code in Local Host FOrmatting is Coming Perfectly but after hosted application on server formatting is not Coming Correctly.

as i mentioned in the Screen Shots.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Sorry for that coz its my First Time.

Comment: Still.. what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try code like below.  The tab widths will vary depending on the output device.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);


            List<List<string>> inputs = new List<List<string>>() {
                 new List<string>() {"Template ID", "Node Tree", "Row Number", "Column Name", "Error Type"," Error"},
                 new List<string>() {"Description 21843 ", "VOUCHER", "16428000","","Error", "Parent Name is not Correct"}
            };

            foreach (List<string> input in inputs)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join("\t|", input));
            }


            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```